# How to decide length when working with UTF-8 in PHP + MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

We are developing website based on the multilingual concept. we have set the character set as UTF8 in database field. but, my question is " How to decide length when working with UTF-8"? what is the ideal way to define UTF8 in database and what should be the length of it?

For example, on admin side there will be a CMS page module where admin can enter content based on the language section option. let say, I have set the content field length(10) into the database table and on back-end side, Admin will select the "French" language and save the content. 
There can be different language section options. If admin will enter data in plan text then will it be stored in database with given length and character set for selected language?

Please do needful on this.

Comment: Is there any reason for you *at all* to be working so close to the limits to begin with? Would there be any issue if you effectively allowed unlimited input, or set the limit somewhere so high that you won't bump against it in practical use? What are you trying to limit and for what purpose in the first place?

Comment: UTF8 is working fine with english language but  untill we're adding Arabic or Japanese letters キ.my question is, I want to verify the length and store it in my DB. because one Japanese letter is already 8-bit compared to a normal letter that is 1-bit. what i have to set the length of the field for UTF-8 character in database?

Comment: An ASCII character is 1 ***byte*** (not bit), Japanese characters are 3 or 4 ***bytes*** (not sure if there's any character in the 2 byte range which can be considered Japanese), when encoded in UTF-8. So, worst case, you multiply your maximum length by 4. BUT, MySQL measures the limit in *characters*, not bytes, so this concern is pretty useless to begin with. Additionally, with languages so divers as French, Arabic and Japanese, it seems nonsensical to have limits in the range of +-10 anyway. So again, is there any issue with simply not worrying about limits?

Comment: I am just worring about length with UTF-8. if i set the length (10) in database for UTF 8 character set. will it store any language data in database? or there is any issue while storing? because i don't know about language Arabic,French language content length.

Comment: What is the ideal length size for VARCHAR for UTF-8 character for multilingual contents

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Comment: Content can we blog size or paragraph size.

Comment: That was actually a [rhetorical question](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/how_long_is_a_piece_of_string)... **If** you need an actual number, then start by measuring the actual length of actual expected content. Otherwise you have absolutely nothing to base any decision on. What I'm trying to tell you is: **just use `TEXT` instead of `VARCHAR(x)`** if you have no basis to decide on a value for `x`.

Comment: According to our requirement we can not use TEXT in all the case. we need some specific solution regarding the varchar length according to the utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

`TEXT` will do for any civilized paragraph in *any* language.  `MEDIUMTEXT` will work for any sane blog.  Do use `utf8mb4`, not `utf8`.

End of discussion.